# AWS Lambda: Unable to import module 'python_handler': No module named '_cffi_backend'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, sftp, paramiko

I'm creating a AWS Lambda function when I need to read an info on an API, create a CSV file, and upload them on a SFTP server.

I've installed paramiko on my venv, using Ubuntu on Windows, and the cffi module comes like a dependency, but when the code runs, I receive this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'python_handler': No module named '_cffi_backend'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Follow my code:

```py
import paramiko
import requests
from random import randrange
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Lambda function
    addZero = lambda x : '0' + str(x) if x < 10 else str(x)

    # Actual datetime
    ac_yr = datetime.utcnow().year
    ac_mo = datetime.utcnow().month
    ac_da = datetime.utcnow().day
    ac_hh = datetime.utcnow().hour
    ac_mi = datetime.utcnow().minute
    ac_se = datetime.utcnow().second

    # 24 hours ago
    ag_yr = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)).year
    ag_mo = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)).month
    ag_da = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)).day
    ag_hh = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)).hour
    ag_mi = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)).minute
    ag_se = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)).second

    # API Infos
    api_key = 'XYZ'
    page_id = 'XYZ'

    # Call API
    param = {
        'sort_order': 'asc',
        'from': '{}-{}-{}T{}:{}:{}.000Z'.format(ag_yr, addZero(ag_mo), addZero(ag_da), addZero(ag_hh), addZero(ag_mi), addZero(ag_se)),
        'to': '{}-{}-{}T{}:{}:{}.000Z'.format(ac_yr, addZero(ac_mo), addZero(ac_da), addZero(ac_hh), addZero(ac_mi), addZero(ac_se))
    }
    r = requests.get('https://api.unbounce.com/pages/{}/leads'.format(page_id), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, 'pass'), params=param)

    # If connection it's ok
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # If has any result
        if len(r.json()['leads']) > 0:
            cont = ''
            for lead in r.json()['leads']:
                cont += lead['form_data']['cpf'][0] + ','
                cont += lead['form_data']['nome_completo'][0] + ','
                cont += lead['form_data']['email'][0]
        else:
            return 'Não há resultados no momento'
    else:
        return 'Falha na conexão'

    # Write a CSV file
    f = open('my_csv.csv','w')
    f.write('PAC_ID, PAC_NAME, PAC_EMAIL\n')
    f.write(cont)
    f.close()

    transport = paramiko.Transport(('host-info', 22))
    transport.connect(None, 'user-info', 'password-info', None)

    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    sftp.chdir('Import')
    sftpclient.put('my_csv.csv')

    return 'OK'
```

Any idea how  I can solve this?

Comment: Do you get this error when you run on AWS or on your private env?

Comment: @balderman, on AWS

Comment: Did you create a deployment package?

Comment: @balderman, yeah, without the sftp part, work's well!
When I add pysftp or paramiko, the error occours.

Comment: So it is quite clear that paramiko  (or paramiko dependency ) needs a dependency that you dont provide - isnt it?

Comment: try `pip install cffi` into the package that you upload.

Comment: @balderman, It looks like, but... "Requirement already satisfied"... on my machine, it's all ok, this error occurs just on Lambda.

Comment: The question is what goes into the zip file that you upload to AWS. Check the zip file content.

Comment: @balderman, the zip it's ok, including the cffi.

Comment: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4223 - this is the best(?) link I have found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on Ubuntu, I haven't the success with pysftp or paramiko to Lambda.
So I created an EC2 instance (and after an VirtualBox with Amazon Linux 2) on my desktop and develop the same code, with the same libraries. And... that's works...

Comment: OP should use this Docker container - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/ - see below answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64780521/6233477) for more info.

Comment: I don't think this answer realises just how correct it actually is - the version of the Lambda runtime needs to match the version of the build container too, at least as far as this particular library is concerned. (eg py39 runtime won't work when the build container is py38)

Answer (score 9):

You can also get the error `No module named '_cffi_backend'` when the runtime version of your AWS Lambda function is different than the python version used to create your Lambda Layer.

I received this error when I set the runtime of my Lambda Function to Python 3.10, but I installed the dependencies for my Lambda Layer in an environment that was running Python 3.8.

Comment: confirm, I had to use 3.8 instead of 3.9. I didn't find the way to build it with 3.9 version yet. On 20 July 2023

Comment: If you're using instructions from OzNetNerd, you can replace the lambci image with the official ones from AWS. All you need to do is replace "lambci/lambda:build-python3.7" with "public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9"

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use the  [lambci/lambda](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) container as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/). I wrote about it in some detail [here.](https://oznetnerd.com/2020/11/11/lambda-packaging-the-right-way/)

In a nutshell, some Python packages (e.g `cffi`) have OS level dependencies. Because the OS you're packaging the code on is different to the one Lambda uses, the script fails to run.

Comment: As of July 2023, lambci containers only support up to Python 3.8. Making a note here that OzNetNerds instructions are still relevant, but the official aws builds should be used instead: https://gallery.ecr.aws/sam

e.g. public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.10

Answer (score 1):

may be late, hopefully, will help someone in future. this answer is specific to "_cffi_backend.....". One other thing that may help is to know how you installed python. if did using brew, you will need to create a virtual env using python. see here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

i did this in a linux environment without downloading the wheel files that are compatible with various linux distros and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Using `serverless` cli with `serverless-python-requirements` plugin, if you change the AWS Lambda python runtime version and publish, the plugin will use the same pip download cache which was using the old python version. (This cache is outside your git repo, so `git clean` doesn't help either.)

That would resulting in having `_cffi_backend.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in your lambda, even though you expect to use `cpython-311`.

The fix is to run `serverless requirements cleanCache` to delete the pip download cache.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a common problem with many binary packages.
I don't have a generic solution yet, but what you really have to do is to move (symlink) the binary file from where it is really installed to the root of your package.

I usually solve this with post-install scripts for my Lambdas. The ones using `paramiko` run something like:

```
ln -s venv/MY_LAMBDA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so MY_LAMBDA/
ln -s venv/MY_LAMBDA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/.libs_cffi_backend/libffi-XXXXXXXX.so.6.0.4 MY_LAMBDA/
ln -s venv/MY_LAMBDA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nacl MY_LAMBDA/
```

You will have to identify the exact name of the `libffi...` file from your virtualenv. It might vary from the machine you compile the library on.